What could be the reasons my young palm is turning brown
I planted a younger palm last summer. It seems like it got pretty well established, but this spring, it started turning brown.
I used some of this: https://www.amazon.com/Miracle-Gro-3002910-Shake-Continuous-Release/dp/B01MQYMWYH/
But it had little to no effect.

I am in Zone 8 and I have another slightly larger palm 20' away that is doing just fine.
thanks in advance.

Are you sure this is not normal?  It looks like its the bottom fronds that are falling off, and from what little I've observed of my palm trees (which granted are very different to these), fronds at the bottom die off and new fronds grow from the top.

Thanks for the comment.  Yes it looks like that is apart of the problem.  But the top ones seem to be doing it as well. I'll cut the bottom ones back and take another picture.

Did you dilute the fertilizer?
